# How do I make it so that an array of users can display an array of photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Basically I am trying to display @arts = @users.arts, where User has many arts and @users is a plurality of users. I am getting back and undefined method for arts. Thanks in advance

Comment: a question: does an Art belong_to User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not able to do this because you're calling an instance method on something that's not an instance. A "plurality of users" in this case is a sort of Array, and it does not have the `arts` relationship defined. What you need is:

```
@arts = @users.collect { |user| user.arts }.flatten
```

You can also use other more advanced methods to collect all of these in one query but that should be a start.

Comment: Ruby 1.9: @users.flat_map(&:arts)